# Single phase energy meter reports Phase current as 0A but neutral current 1A

Tags: mains, distribution-network

When I switch off all my appliances, my single phase energy meter reports phase current(Ph) as 0A, but neutral current(nE) as 1A.

Also on the meter display it is flashing the earth symbol.
The KWh counter is also increasing.

I'm familiar with some electrical but not an expert in house wiring. Any help what is going on?

Comment: across - Hi, Practical mains wiring questions should be asked at [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com) where practical home electrical questions (as could be asked to an electrical contractor / electrician) are [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). || Due to some people not engaging with questions after migration, causing wasted time on the destination site and then blaming us for doing the migration, I'm not going to migrate this question. Instead, I recommend that you ask there & please include your country and ideally a photo of the meter (or at least its make & model).

Comment: @SamGibson I was not aware of DIY community . Thank you for the link and suggestions. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be an earth fault, which is dangerous. An earth fault would be caught and prevented by an RCD by disconnecting the faulty load if the RCD is fitted in the circuit upstream of the fault.

The other possibility is that the meter is mis reporting.

I think you are best getting a qualified electrician in ASAP.

Comment: The earth symbol is going away when I turn OFF the MCB immediately after meter. Looks like there is some earth fault. I'll get an electrician thank you so much!